# Textinputlayout change textcolorhint when text present

Tags: android, textcolor, android-textinputlayout

*Little add: I need a way of doing it when the TextInputLayout/EditText is not focused, not between focused-not focused states*

---

I'm looking for a way to change the `textColorHint` property of `TextInputLayout` **only when the text is present** in the `TextInputEditText` (directly from XML).

If I use that property `android:textColorHint="@color/black"`, it changes the hint color also if the `TextInputEditText` is empty.

Is there a way to set two different colors for the hint in the two states?
I add a couple of images to explain better

## What I want:

- when text is empty[image: empty]
- when text is filled[image: text]

## What I don't want:

- hint has "with text" color[image: wrong]

---

*post scriptum: yeah, I could've used two more different colors for this example, but it should be understandable anyway :P*

Comment: Do you want the same hint color for both a) "input-filled with focus"  and b) "input-filled without focus" but different for "empty-text" ?

Comment: @KrishnaSharma not really, if you look image 1 and 2, I want the "Phone Number" text color to be different in the two cases. (both not-focused) :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you take two color, lets say **color1** when text is empty and **color2** when text is filled, try below approach.

**When Text Filled**

```
<style name="TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout_filled" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color2</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_12</item>

</style>
```

**When Text Empty**

```
<style name="TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout_empty" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color1</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_12</item>

</style>
```

**Theme**

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">

    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/color1</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_16</item>

</style>
```

**XML for TextInputLayout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_first_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout_filled">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_first_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/first_name_caps"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/til_last_name"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**and code**

```
edt_first_name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            if (edt_first_name.getText().toString().length() > 0){
                til_first_name.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_App_TextInputLayout_filled);
            }else {
                til_first_name.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_App_TextInputLayout_empty);
            }

        }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but as I reported, I was wandering if there is a way of doing it XML-side only

Answer (score 0):

Use style

```
<style name="TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/color_hint</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_black</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/helveticaneue</item>
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_hint</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/color_hint</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/color_hint</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/color_hint</item>
</style>
```

use this style in xml

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutFirstName"
                style="@style/TextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextInputStyle.Hint">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editFirstName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/first_name"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"
                    android:theme="@style/InputTextEditTextNew" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for replying, probably you missunderstood the event: I don't want to change the color whether it is focused or not (what your answer perfectly does), I want two different colors for the "text-filled" and "text-empty" scenarios, in both case without the focus on edittext

Answer (score 0):

For the `TextInputEditText` set the color of the hint when it is empty with this attribute:  
`android:textColorHint="@color/yourcolor"`  
when it is not empty you have to set the color of the floating hint with this style:

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colornormalcolor</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/anothercolor</item>
</style>
```

and use it in the `TextInputLayout` xml:

```
android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! I tried this, but it changes the color to the "colorControlActivated" only if the EditText is focused. If it is filled but not focused, the color is still the textColorHint

Comment: set this color to colorControlNormal

Comment: unfortunatly the hint (in both cases) is always of "textColorHint" color, colorControlNormal is never used

Comment: * If it is filled but not focused* then the color is the `textColor` attribute of the EditText. Don't you have one?

Comment: I have it, I mean the *hint* title color (watch images 1 and 2 in my question, the hint is the "Phone number" text)

Comment: when it is not filled (first image) I need the "Phone number" to be of color A, when the text is written (not focused, second image) "Phone number" should be of color B

Comment: Finally I see what you need, but it seems in both cases `android:textColorHint` is used

Comment: yeah :( I hoped there was a way for doing it automatically from XML

Answer (score 0):

After some research looks like we can not achieve **what we are looking for** from xml layout only. To do that we definitely need to customize `TextInputLayout`. Then can simply use that in xml layout file wherever is required.

Here is the customized `TextInputLayout`

```
public class CustomTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        registerFocusChangeListener();
    }

    private void registerFocusChangeListener() {
        getEditText().setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                String text = getEditText().getText().toString();
                boolean isEmpty = TextUtils.isEmpty(text);
                if (!isEmpty) { // EditText is not empty, doesn't matter whether it is focused or unfocused
                    setHintTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_Dark);
                } else {  // EditText is empty
                    setHintTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_Light);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```